# How to pass variables from one php page to another without form?

Tags: php, variables

I want to know how to pass a variable from one page to another in PHP without any form.

What I want to achieve is this:

1. The user clicks on a link
2. A variable is passed which contains a string.
3. The variable can be accessed on the other page so that I can run mysql queries using that variable.

Comment: `<a href="page2.php?variable1=value1&foo=bar">Anchors</a>` is what you do then, accept techjunkie's answer, it's what you want.

Comment: Just remember that nothing about that variable string can be trusted in a query. Don't open yourself to SQL injection!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use the get method in the url. If you want to pass over a variable called 'phone' as 0001112222:

```
<a href='whatever.php?phone=0001112222'>click</a>
```

then on the next page (whatever.php) you can access this var via:

```
$_GET['phone']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked for me ! Though all the answers were correct!

Comment: I'm getting the error Undefined index: event in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql\trial_rsvp.php on line 43

Any help on this ?

$event=$_GET['event'];

Comment: probably means an 'event' variable was not passed over in the get. check the url to see if its in there

Answer (score 14):

You want [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) if you have data you want to have the data held for longer than one page.

`$_GET` for just one page.

`<a href='page.php?var=data'>Data link</a>`

on `page.php`

```
<?php
echo $_GET['var'];
?>
```

will output: data

Comment: +1 for pointing `if you have data you want to have the data held for longer than one page` this is a useful note

Answer (score 1):

You can pass via GET. So if you want to pass the value `foobar` from `PageA.php` to `PageB.php`, call it as `PageB.php?value=foobar`.

In PageB.php, you can access it this way:

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure the variable is set. Then clean it before using it:

```
isset($_GET['var'])?$var=mysql_escape_string($_GET['var']):$var='SomeDefaualtValue';
```

Otherwise, assign it a default value (`$var=''` is fine) to avoid the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax calls or $_GET["String"]; Method

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the variable from another PHP file directly, you can include that file with `include()` or `include_once()`, giving you access to that variable. Note that this will include the **entire first file** in the second file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While answers are always appreciated, please note that this question was asked 6 years ago, and already had an accepted solution. Also, it's important to note that including a file in with `include()` includes the **entire file**, not just the variable (which may not be intentional). I've edited your answer to make note of this. Check out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)