# Passing values of textbox to another page html

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, move

Hi guys this may be a silly question but if I have a html page open that contains a textbox is it possible to move the value of that textbox to another page onces a button is clicked?

So "page1.html" has a textbox called "TextboxName", User types in name "John", button is clicked and then that Page is closed and "John" is moved to the textbox on "page2.html"

Thanks in advance for any help this problem really has stumped me!

Comment: Many ways. Easiest - pass it in a query string `page2.html?TextboxName=John`. Google it up

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code:

Page1.html:

```
<html>
  <form type=get action="page2.html">
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=firstname size=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Last Name:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=lastname size=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=age size=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=2><input type=submit value="Submit">
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</html>
```

Page2.html:

```
<html>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function getParams(){
  var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
  var params = new Array();
  if (idx != -1) {
    var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
    nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
    params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
    }
  }
  return params;
 }
params = getParams();
firstname = unescape(params["firstname"]);
lastname = unescape(params["lastname"]);
age = unescape(params["age"]);
document.write("firstname = " + firstname + "<br>");
document.write("lastname = " + lastname + "<br>");
document.write("age = " + age + "<br>");
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You are creating `var params` as a `new Array()` but then use it as an object.  You should use `var params = {};`

Comment: This is great, but On the second page they are not textboxes? I need to move it from page1 to page2 so that I can save it to a Database on page 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but it requires something other than just plain html.  Javascript or PHP could easily accomplish such a function.

See this: [How to pass variables from one php page to another without form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252418/how-to-pass-variables-from-one-php-page-to-another-without-form)

Or try javascript + AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

and: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/passingp.htm

You could also store the information in a cookie and access it that way: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/cookies.htm

or just use angular: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

Answer (score 0):

On page1.html do:

```
function onClickHandler(){
    location.href = 'page2.html?name=' + document.getElementById('TextBoxName').value;
}
```

then on page2.html do:

```
function parseQueryString()
{
    var queryDict = {}
    location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
        queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]
    });

    return queryDict;
}

function onLoadHandler(){
    document.getElementById('TextBoxName').value = parseQueryString().name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how much effort and work you want to put into your project.

One easy -but not secure- solution is possible via [querystrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You could pass via `HTTP-GET` any parameter from A to B.

Hence it is provided als plaintext, it is obvious, that this method is not very safe. Anybody could change the input at any given time. And the result depends on the malicious potential of your attacker. Look here for a simple introduction to [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/573458/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Cross-Site-Scrip).

Another possibility is via `HTTP-Post` ([See Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)).

Then it depends on which backend you are using. The backend receives the data from A and renders it to B.