# How to pass variable to another page without include

Tags: php

Hey guys I'm trying to pass a php variable to another page. I tried it with sessions but no result.

```
newspaper.php

$newspaper= $newspaper['newspath'];
print_r($newspaper);
```

this outputs:

```
path/to/the/newspaper.
```

Now I want to use the variable in the second page.

```
newspaperviewer.php

echo $newspaper;
$SESSION = $newspaper;
```

I tried the first one but no result. The second one seems to be faulty.

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: You are not using session correctly. Do you want to give you a solution with session?

Comment: try using: `newspaperviewer.php?new=$newspaper` in other page get it like `$_GET['new']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables from one php page to another without form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252418/how-to-pass-variables-from-one-php-page-to-another-without-form)

Comment: @Suchit I've never done an include like that, I thought it had to be an absolute path, does that work? I thought `$_GET` was only for browser access, but does it work using `include / require`? :P

Comment: the missing piece for you is [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: no you have to redirect to the destination with this url.

Comment: Your example - a path - smells to me more like a configuration option.  A common constant.  In that case an include fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session is what you are looking for. A session variable can store a value and use this value on all pages of your project.
First thing to do is to start session on each file on your project. You can do this like this example

```
<?php
session_start(); //declare you are starting a session
$_SESSION['newspaper'] = "New York Times"; //Assign a value to the newspaper session
?>
```

On the other file you can use the value of the session by trying something like this

```
<?php
session_start(); //always start session don't forget!!
echo $_SESSION['newspaper'];
// This will echo New York Times
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Could you edit the newspare name? thanks.

Comment: but no need to start session more than one time..with the same domain.

Comment: @DavidBrett i'am happy to hear that. You can make multiple session with different names, just copy the example and change the session name to your needs :)

Comment: @HikmatSijapati from my experience i can't use session if i dont declare it in each file, expept when i incude the files to a file that i have declare it before, in this case you are correct

Comment: @Rafael Shkembi you have some wrong experience... session is always started once. not need to declare at every page.and another important thing is  never need to use include if you want to use session.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati, bunkum you are wrong.  You must use session_start in every request to assign or retrieve variables to/from a session.

Comment: I know the construction. No problem I didn't started a new session. cause the sesson starts at the begin when I'm log in.

Answer (score 3):

Store the variable after starting session on `page A`, like so:

```
// FIRST PAGE (foo.php)
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Jack';
```

Now, on the second page (or any page that you want to have access to `$_SESSION`, simply do the same but pull the variable.

```
// SECOND PAGE (bar.php)
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$_SESSION['name'] = null; // Or use session_unset() to delete all SESSION vars.
```

And that's how you pass variables using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Looks like the OP has tried to use Sessions, but is doing so incorrectly.  Can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

First

```
newspaper.php

$newspaper= $newspaper['newspath'];
//print_r($newspaper);
session_start(); //it starts your session here
$_SESSION['newspaper']=$newspaper; //it sets a session variable named as newspaper
```

Second

```
$newspaper= isset($_SESSION['newspaper'])?$_SESSION['newspaper']:''; //checks and sets value
echo $newspaper; //outputs value
```

For more see [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Needs `session_start()` on second  to populate $_SESSION for later retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to set session

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
newspaper.php

session_start();
$newspaper= $newspaper['newspath'];
$_SESSION['newspaper'] = $newspaper;
```

Now you can use this session variable in

```
newspaperviewer.php

session_start();
$newspaper = $_SESSION['newspaper'];
echo $newspaper;
session_unset(); // remove all session variables
```